# Switching from immediate mode to VBOs in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I currently use immediate mode to draw simple 2D textured Quads with LWJGL and I'm well aware this is deprecated and VBOs are a much more modern way of drawing. However, when I first started to learn LWJGL I learned to draw with immediate mode instead of using VBOs.

The issue is I have made a game that relies on immediate mode to draw hundreds of quads on screen at one time. So I was wondering if there is any easy way to make the switch to VBOs to help increase performance.

Comment: I mean that my entire game has been built from the ground up with immediate mode rendering where I can Use glTranslate to change where it is drawn glRotate etc. and I’m wondering if this will apply in the same way to VBOs where I won’t have to rework the entire position detection/movement scheme of the game

Comment: Check my example https://github.com/incoder1/JavaGPU/tree/master/src/main/java/org/dou/opengl